# Modal Dialog window with Selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, rspec

So I'm trying to navigate to a page in IE9 using Selenium that, when loading the page, says there is a certificate error. Using AutoIT I'm able to get it to click within the browser and then TAB twice then hit enter, no problems. However when it continues, it throws a "Modal dialog present error". Here's the method that is to supposed to handle IE Security Warning errors:

```
# Handle IE Security Warning errors.
class  Selenium::WebDriver::Navigation
  def to(url)
  @bridge.get url
  if @bridge.getTitle.match(/Certificate Error.*/)
      Thread.new do
        sleep 0.75
        security_warning = 'Security Warning'
        if @auto_it.WinActive(security_warning)
             @auto_it.ControlClick(security_warning, "Yes", '[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2]' )
      end
       auto_it = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
       auto_it.WinWait('[CLASS:IEFrame]','', 90)
       x = auto_it.WinGetPosX('[CLASS:IEFrame]') 
       y = auto_it.WinGetPosY('[CLASS:IEFrame]')
       auto_it.MouseClick("left", x + 100, y + 200, 1, 0) 
       auto_it.Send "{TAB 2}{ENTER}"
       sleep 0.25
       wait.until { @bridge.executeScript("return document.readyState;") == "complete" }
    end
  end
end
```

The best that I can do here is below the "sleep 0.25" call is to do this:

```
auto_it.Send "{TAB}{ENTER}"
```

(Except the {ENTER} doesn't do anything, it just hangs there until the test times out)

I need to know how to get Selenium to interface with that dialog box that pops up. I know that Selenium doesn't handle them very well (which is why AutoIT is being used). Any ideas?

P.S. This is not my code, This method was created by my co-worker

Answer (score 0):

If this is typical SSL certificate error warning displayed in IE, then you may want to use JavascriptExecutor to handle it, as described in detail in this blog post:

http://automatictester.co.uk/2014/08/03/handling-ssl-certificate-errors-in-selenium/

In general, try to avoid mixing AutoIT with Selenium, unless you really have to.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the script already using JavascriptExecutor to a degree? Following the link that you had provided, it has an example that uses the same syntax as the

    @bridge.executeScript(...)

lines that I had mentioned in my post.